# Get Model object instead of Eloquent Builder object

Tags: php, laravel-5

I need to fetch one record from my users table with some conditions and for that i wrote below code.

```
$user = UserModel::where(['company_id' => $id, 'roles' => 'Owner', 'NOW()' < 'request_access']);
```

This gives me an object of Eloquent Builder but i need Model object. How can I get that?

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOW()` mysql method like this

```
$user = UserModel::where(['company_id' => $id, 'roles' => 'Owner'])->where("request_access", ">", DB::raw("NOW()"))->first();
```